# Flutter Auth with WiX

Tags: flutter, api, backend, velo

I am a beginner level developer. I have a WiX website and some authorized members in it. Now, I am creating an app for my website (in Flutter) and I want all of the members' login info in my app so that they could login to my app just like they login to my website. How can I do that?

I literally have no idea how to do that. I'll be glad and honored if someone would like to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this through an API. I don't know if Wix has a plugin for generating API, otherwise you have to build one yourself

Comment: Is it possible to create my own API when I do not know their database link or access of my members?

Comment: You need to know the database link. You can ask more about the database they use in the wix community